# Lubuntu 14.04 - can't connect via wi-fi after deleting and re-creating connection

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I had a wi-fi connection to my Amped APA20 access point working fine, but I deleted the connection and when I re-created it, now Lubuntu won't connect. Nothing else on the system has changed. Could the system have information in a file somewhere which is preventing the re-created connection from working? I created a new wi-fi connection using my cell phone as a mobile hotspot, temporarily, which works fine.

[Additional info: I had the APA20 set to not broadcast the SSID. When I set it to broadcast, the wi-fi connection is seen by Lubuntu and it connects. This is contrary to past experience, though- I have been able to connect to hidden (non-broadcast) wi-fi networks before.

Update- when I set the APA20 back to not broadcasting the SSID, Lubuntu can now connect to the network. Why it can connect now and couldn't before is somewhat of a mystery.]

Answer (score 0):

You can try manually deleting anything that might be left over.

1. Open a terminal
2. Enter `cd /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`
3. Enter `ls` to see what's in the directory
4. Enter `sudo rm <filename>` to delete a connection

You might have to log out and back in for it to take effect. The Ubuntu Network Manager tends not to like it when you manually delete connections.

Comment: @user25635 You should edit your question and add this info to help others figure out answers.